# Can't find ejabberd yml file in ubuntu 14.04 after installation

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04, yaml, ejabberd

I recently installed a ejabberd server on an ubuntu 14.04 aws server by following the article http://tecadmin.net/install-ejabberd-xmpp-server-on-ubuntu/

However, after installation, I can't seem to find the yml file in the folder /etc/ejabberd/ and only see a cfg file instead.

I also tried reinstalling but the yml file does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

`ejabberd.cfg` file use the old Erlang term format instead of Yaml format. I guess Ubuntu packager did not convert the file format yet when package was build or did package an old version of ejabberd. It is fine and should work, but you should likely use a more recent version to get started.

Comment: Thanks!! I realized after checking the docs that if you use apt-get to install you will always get ejabberd version 2.1.11. I had to install using binary packages to get the most updated version of ejabberd